# Eloquent relationships for not-existing model class

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I would like to have in my applications many models/modules but some of them would be removed for some clients.

Now I have such relation:

```
public function people()
{
    return $this->hasMany('People', 'model_id');
}
```

and when I run `$model = Model::with('people')->get();` it is working fine

But what if the `People` model doesn't exist?

At the moment I'm getting:

> 1/1 ErrorException in ClassLoader.php line 386: include(...): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory

I tried with

```
public function people()
{ 
    try {
       return $this->hasMany('People', 'model_id');
    }
    catch (FatalErrorException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

or with:

```
public function people()
{ 
    return null; // here I could add checking if there is a Model class and if not return null
}
```

but when using such method `$model = Model::with('people')->get();` doesn't work.

I will have a dozens of relations and I cannot have list of them to use in `with`. The best method for that would be using some `empty relation` (returning null) just to make Eloquent not to do anything but in this case Eloquent still tries to make it work and I will get:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>   1/1 FatalErrorException in Builder.php line 430: Call to a member function 
>   addEagerConstraints() on null

Is there any simple solution for that?

Comment: It seems very odd, why would you remove models at all?

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk If the clients don't need some functionality/don't pay for them they won't have this functionality (those files with models for instance) but other clients who pay for it should have the functionality. And I don't want to change other models that are related to models that might be removed. It's not fully my conception but I try to find out if it might be done.

Comment: I understand the concept of features enabled/disabled for the clients. What I don't get is the way you're implementing it with removig files. If you deliver the code, not saas, then I would suggest creating independent packages that you can simply plugin or not, depending on the client.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk I will have for a module that can display list of people. If other modules are not enabled it should display only a list of people, but if module A is enabled it should also display for each person some info from A module (relation) and if module B is enabled it should display some info from B module and probably if A and B modules are enabled I will have to display info from both A & B module on people list. It's at the moment only conception from my client not the final solution. Maybe you could recommend some other implementation for this?

Answer (score 7):

The only solution I could come up with is creating your own `Eloquent\Builder` class.

I've called it `MyBuilder`. Let's first make sure it gets actually used. In your model (preferably a Base Model) add this `newEloquentBuilder` method:

```
public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
{
    return new MyBuilder($query);
}
```

In the custom `Builder` class we will override the `loadRelation` method and add an `if null` check right before `addEagerConstraints` is called on the relation (or in your case on `null`)

```
class MyBuilder extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {
    protected function loadRelation(array $models, $name, Closure $constraints)
    {
        $relation = $this->getRelation($name);


        if($relation == null){
            return $models;
        }


        $relation->addEagerConstraints($models);

        call_user_func($constraints, $relation);

        $models = $relation->initRelation($models, $name);

        $results = $relation->getEager();

        return $relation->match($models, $results, $name);
    }
}
```

The rest of the function is basically the identical code from the original builder (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`)

Now simply add something like this in your relation function and it should all work:

```
public function people()
{
    if(!class_exist('People')){
        return null;
    }
    return $this->hasMany('People', 'model_id');
}
```

### Update: Use it *like* a relationship

If you want to use it like you can with a relationship it gets a bit more tricky.

You have to override the `getRelationshipFromMethod` function in `Eloquent\Model`. So let's create a Base Model (Your model obviously needs to extend it then...)

```
class BaseModel extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    protected function getRelationshipFromMethod($key, $camelKey)
    {
        $relations = $this->$camelKey();

        if ( $relations instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection){
            // "fake" relationship
            return $this->relations[$key] = $relations;
        }
        if ( ! $relations instanceof Relation)
        {
            throw new LogicException('Relationship method must return an object of type '
                . 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation');
        }

        return $this->relations[$key] = $relations->getResults();
    }
}
```

Now we need to modify the relation to return an empty collection

```
public function people()
{
    if(!class_exist('People')){
        return new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();
    }
    return $this->hasMany('People', 'model_id');
}
```

And change the `loadRelation` function in `MyBuilder` to check for the type collection instead of `null`

```
protected function loadRelation(array $models, $name, Closure $constraints)
{
    $relation = $this->getRelation($name);

    if($relation instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection){
        return $models;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, at the moment it seems to be very close to what I need. However now when I want to for example loop for people I need to use something like that: `if ($model->people() === null) {} else {if (count($model->people) == 0) {echo "no people";} else {foreach $model->people ... }`. Is there any chance to return by relation empty model, track it in MyBuilder just to break as you did, to make possible to use standard access: `if (count($model->people) == 0) {echo "no people";} else {foreach $model->people ... }` I tried to create empty relation but without success.

Comment: I updated the question. However, I'm not able to test it at the moment. Let me know if it works.