# Eloquent custom relation return type error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm having some troubles with a custom relation.
I want `$user->sites` to return every site `$user` got access to. It's a belongsToMany relationship, with a pivot table 'user_site'. The problem is, when `$user` is an admin, he has access to every site in the database, and I can't manage to get it to work with Eloquent.

```
public function sites() {
  if( $this->is_super_user )
    return Site::whereNotNull('deleted_at');

  return $this->belongsToMany('Site', 'user_site');
}
```

This is what I got, but it isn't working (Relationship method must return an object of type `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`).

I could just return `Site::all()` and `$this->belongsToMany('Site', 'user_site)->get()`, but I want to be able to use the dynamic property (`$user->sites`) and to filter the result (`$user->sites()->where...`)

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460614/eloquent-relationships-for-not-existing-model-class/27461288#27461288) It's not exactly the same problem but it may help

Comment: Why would you do it this way at all? If you are an admin, then simply use `Sites::all()` or whatever it should be. Using relationship when there's no relationship at all is making things hard. And for the Eloquent - you can't return anything that is not extending `Relation` class, so this one won't work.

Comment: Sites::whereNotNull(..) is an unfinished query
You could try Sites::whereNotNull(..)->get(). Not quite shure if that will work though